# Ruby random array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have created a two-dimensional (`4x4`) array, where each element is a random number from `-10` to `10`.

I would like to now print all negative elements of this array in the terminal. How can one do this?

Here is my code so far which initialises the array, along with my current attempt to print all negative values:

```
a = Array.new(4) { rand(-10...10) }

a[0] = Array.new(4) { rand(-10...10) }
a[1] = Array.new(4) { rand(-10...10) }
a[2] = Array.new(4) { rand(-10...10) }
a[3] = Array.new(4) { rand(-10...10) }

a.each {|i|
  a.each {|j|
    puts j
  }
}
```

Comment: Your program seems to work fine. What problem are you having? Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Once readers understand the question, someone will be happy to do an edit to help you with the English. Not to worry. I think it's mainly " and when have negative elemt put this elevent in terminal" that we don't understand.

Comment: update question. need put array element if element negative

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the element (`puts ...`) if it is negative? If so, do you want to display the element's indices as well (e.g., `"a[2,3] = -4"`)?

Comment: `rand` isn't very random. Use something like: `SecureRandom.random_number(-10..10)` instead. `require 'securerandom'` to enable this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need loop it twice.

```
a = Array.new(4) { Array.new(4) { rand(-10..10) } }

a.flatten.each {|x| puts x if x>0}
```

Comment: If you want to do more than just `puts x`, then looping twice is more flexible - for example, you could do `each_with_index`. In addition, this code is ~2.5 times slower. So yes, your code may be slightly more compact, but it comes at a cost.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the `4x4` array much more simply in a single step, as follows:

```
a = Array.new(4) { Array.new(4) { rand(-10..10) } }
```

You can then print all negative values in the `4x4` array via a nested loop:

```
a.each do |row|
  row.each do |cell|
    puts cell if cell < 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'matrix'

n = 4
m = Matrix.build(n) { rand(-10..10) }
  #=> Matrix[[-5, -8, -3, 7], [-5, 5, 2, 7], [-8, -9, 8, 5], [-2, -9, -2, -4]] 
m.each_with_index { |v,r,c| puts "m[%d,%d] = %d" % [r,c,v] if v < 0 }
m[0,0] = -5
m[0,1] = -8
m[0,2] = -3
m[1,0] = -5
m[2,0] = -8
m[2,1] = -9
m[3,0] = -2
m[3,1] = -9
m[3,2] = -2
m[3,3] = -4
```

If you wish to return the associated array:

```
m.to_a
  #=> [[-5, -8, -3, 7], [-5, 5, 2, 7], [-8, -9, 8, 5], [-2, -9, -2, -4]]
```